# Como escribir una funcion Lamdba en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

<sub>**Nota:** Esto es una traduccion de una pregunta de SO en Inglés.</sub>

---

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de VB.net. Soy nuevo con VB.net LINQ y me gustaría saber el equivalente Lambda de

```
var _new = orders.Select(x => x.items > 0);
```

En VB.net

Pregunta original [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317333/how-to-write-a-vb-net-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>**Nota:** Esta es una traducción de la respuesta aceptada de SO en inglés</sub>

---

La sintaxis del lamdba no es muy diferente de un delegado regular.

Si se esta creando un lamdba que retorne algun valor se utiliza `Function`. De lo contrario si no retorna valor utiliza `Sub`

```
Dim _new = orders.Select(Function(x) x.Items > 0)

Dim action As Action(Of Item) = Sub(x) Console.WriteLine(x.Items)
```

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18317375/6273192) la respuesta original